# Fundo com mosaico de fotos

Tags: jquery, html, css

Preciso criar um fundo para meu site no estilo `mosaico` de fotos. Quando a página abrir, o fundo do site é preenchido por fotos, preenchendo a largura total da janela (ou seja, precisa ser responsivo) e uma altura determinada.

[Clique aqui para ver um exemplo animado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XALka.gif) e um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3xuy8g/).

Pesquisei alguns `plugins` e encontrei [este aqui](http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/example1.html). Ele faz exatamente o que quero, porém, ele não trabalha com `background`.

Vocês tem alguma sugestão de plugin? Ou de como posso criar esse efeito?

---

**EDITADO**

A estrutura que eu tenho para listar as imagens é algo parecido com isso:

```
<div class="bg-mosaico">
   <img src="imagem 1" />
   <img src="imagem 2" />
   <img src="imagem 3" />
   ...
</div>
```

É simples, por isso acho que um plugin não seja necessariamente útil, e que eu posso criar uma função simples com o mesmo objetivo. Pesquisei e encontrei isto:

```
var imgMOSAICO = $('.bg-mosaico img');
imgMOSAICO.hide();
imgMOSAICO.each(function() {
   $(this).delay( Math.random()*500+500 ).fadeIn();
});
```

Funciona, as imagens aparecem. O problema é que elas não aparecem uma a uma, elas aparecem quase que todas ao mesmo tempo. E eu preciso que elas fiquem fixas, pois tem que ter uma quantidade exata de imagens.. e dependendo da resolução, elas vão quebrando linha e não pode.

Comment: O código não parece complicado para adaptar (https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/master/jquery.collagePlus.js), chegou a tentar mexer nele?

Comment: Você diz editar o próprio arquivo .js? Pois não tenho muito conhecimento para editar um plugin feito. Hehehe.

Comment: Pode explicar o que é o `background`? Você diz "ao fundo...preenchendo largura total e determinada altura", consegue fazer uma boneca em CSS? . . . (acabo de ver que linkei errado acima, mas sim o [JS do plugin](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6k3xuy8g/ | É o fundo da página. O `mosaico` preencheria a largura total da janela (ou seja, responsivo) e teria uma altura máxima. E em cima disso, o conteúdo do site.

Comment: Ok, o legal é inserir esse tipo de esclarecimento no corpo da pergunta, assim o próximo interessado tem o panorama completo na primeira leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Se as imagens não são dinâmicas, acho melhor fazer uma imagem estática e utilizar como background.
Pra se ajustar ao body use a propriedade `background-size:100% 100%;` do CSS3.

Comment: Sim, enquanto eu não encontro uma solução para a criação do mosaico, eu deixei como uma imagem estática mesmo. valeu.